# jQuery - fading image and text on hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to make 4 box with image on background while on hover fade in and show some text. The images will be different, and will comes from post thumbnail. The box will be a hyperlink to post. In PHP i have this:

```
<div class="kwadraty-post2">
    <?php
    $kwadrat1 = get_theme_mod('box1');
    $postid = url_to_postid( $kwadrat1 ); 
    ?> 
    <a href="<?php echo $kwadrat1 ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $postid ); ?>
        <span><?php echo get_theme_mod('box1_title');?></span>        
    </a>
</div>
```

And i have this in JS script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".kwadraty-post2").MyFadeOverImage({
        normalAlpha: 0.5,
        hoverAlpha: 1,
        normalToneColor: "#000",
        imageWidth: 'auto',
        imageHeight: '100%'
    });
    $(".test").hover(function () {
        $(".kwadraty-post2 span").toggle("slow");

    });

});
```

I use [THIS](http://www.kfsoft.info/home/MyFadeOverImage/) to blackout the image. This what I've made works, but not properly. After hover the  is the image blackout. How I can make that text will be visible after hover on the box, no matter where mouse cursor will be?

I sorry for mistakes in this question, English is not my primary language.

[This is graphical presentation of my struggle with JS :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkG1A.jpg)

Comment: do you want to change the text permanently after first hover?

Comment: i just want to show and hide the text when i hover the box. So i used .toggle, which works fine, but when i set mouse pointer on the text the image back to not active state.

Comment: And where have you applied the test class on hovering which you toggle your span

Comment: Ups, i didn't copy that. The text class is before kwadraty-post2 so it looks like this:
`<div class="test">
<div class="kwadraty-post2">`

sorry for that.

Comment: This is what i have - http://jsfiddle.net/6Z6Ev/5/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use this

```
$(".kwadraty-post2").hover(function () {
        $(".kwadraty-post2 span").toggle("slow");

    });
```

instead  of this

```
$(".test").hover(function () {
        $(".kwadraty-post2 span").toggle("slow");

    });
```

EDIT:
You can add an overlay and then use this css for fading:

```
.overlay{
    z-index:10;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay:hover{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Z6Ev/25/

Comment: i tried that. Here is jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/6Z6Ev/5/ hover the image,then the span and look what happend

Comment: Please check the edited answer and try out the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Dzien dobry, if I am right. Your idea is: when you hover the image, the span (which is a sibling of the image) should be shown. If you un-hover, it should still be there.

```
<a href="#">
   <img class="my-img" src="" />
   <span class="span-text">text</span>
</a>
```

If your code looks like this you can hide the span on default in your css and try something like this in jQuery inside the $(document).ready() function

```
$('.my-img').hover(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.span-text').show();
});
```

Comment: hmm... To show you what i'm thinking about i can show you link with something similar to my idea [click](http://www.kominek.in/) except that the image in this box normaly will be darker(just like background-color:#000 and opacity:0.5 in CSS), and on hover will show span text (default display:none in CSS) somewhere and will be brighter (like opacity:1 in CSS).